# making sure Android app operates as expected when when user leaves GUI and comes back

Tags: android, user-interface, continuations

I have written an Android app that plays audio file.
On the GUI I have a `STOP` button that when pressed stops playing of the audio. If I stay in the app GUI I can stop and start as many time as I want and everything works fine. However, if I start the play and leave the GUI to use some other apps, the audio continues to play. If I go back to my app by tapping on the luncher icon if I tap on `STOP` nothing happens.
How can I make sure that the app operation even if I go out of the GUI and come back is intact and continues to work as expected?

Here is how I play Audio:

```
 Thread thrd = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() 
    {
    AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(....
    track.play();
    while(true) { 
       if (shallContinue)
         track.write(....
    }
```

Also if I go to another app, and then relunch this app by pressing the home buttom and choosing the app from the list of recent apps, the `STOP` button works, but if I relunch by pressing th app luncher icon, then `STOP` is not working any more,

Comment: Can you add some code samples? How you play the music?

Comment: please share the onResume and the code that you use to stop the audio? also share the logcat logs...

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar I don't have an onResume. For stopping the code I have:   public void StopActivity() {
     shallContinue = false;  .... where I use the `shallContinue` to decide should I continue the play or not.

Comment: Do I have to have an `onResume`?

Comment: your `onStart()` and `onResume()` would be called when you come back to the activity http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html.  please update your post with code for stopping the audio... how do you use `shallContinue` flag to stop the audio?

Comment: Here is how I use `shallContinue`:                                `while(true)
                    {
                       
                        if (shallContinue) 
                           track.write(...);
                    }`

Comment: please add these to question.. its hard to read code in the comment....

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar I modified the code in question.

Comment: did you check the value of `shallContinue` in the loop after calling the `stopActivity()` after coming back to the `UI`?

Comment: If I do this in debug mode everything works fine, but when I run the code in normal mode it does not work as expected.